# Dnat prerouting does not work on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, iptables, port-forwarding, nat

I've got a Ubuntu 14.04 server used as firewall, router, dhcp, dns and proxy. Everything works properly from inside to the internet, but the forwarding from outside to the inside network doesn't work.

My rules used to work nicely with Ubuntu 10.10 but now I’m migrating to 14.04 and having problems.

I’ve tried to simplify the rules even using just those to rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.10
```

considering that the eth0 is my outside interface, how receives the direct internet IP and my network is `192.168.0.0/24`.

Does anybody have an idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved changing the ethernet card. I really think there was something wrong with the old one.